Period Mapping in Wells' "Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds"
In Wells' "Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds", he defines a period mapping in p. 209, but frankly, I'm unsure what he is trying to do. Either I somehow fail to understand it, or the approach he used back in 1980 just makes no sense.
I shall begin by summarizing the content. Consider a compact Kahler manifold $X$ of complex dimension $n$ and with associated fundamental form $\Omega$. The operator $L = \Omega \wedge -$ has a right adjoint $L^*$ with respect to the Hodge inner product on forms. A $r$-form $\varphi$ is primitive if $L^* \varphi = 0$, or equivalently, $r \leq n$ and $L^{n-r+1} \varphi = 0$. Now assume $r \leq n$. Descending to the level of cohomology, the primitive cohomology is defined as
$$P^r(X, \mathbb{C}) = \{[\varphi] \in H^r(X, \mathbb{C}) \mid L^{n-r+1} \varphi = 0\}$$
The Hodge decomposition of $H^r$ induces the decomposition
$$P^r(X, \mathbb{C}) = \bigoplus_{p+q=r} P^{p,q}(X, \mathbb{C})$$
And I think here is where things begin to make no sense. The subspace $P^{p,q}(X, \mathbb{C})$ thus defines a point $\Phi(X)$ in the Grassmannian $Gr_h(P^r(X, \mathbb{C}))$, where $h = \dim P^{p,q}(X, \mathbb{C})$, and the map $X \mapsto \Phi(X)$ is (what he calls) the period mapping.
What puzzles me is that this map $\Phi$ has no clear domain. In fact, it looks more like a functor to me, perhaps from the category of Kahler manifolds to some other category. Also, I am not sure whether he is trying to work with a fixed pair $(p,q)$. This "definition" also seems to differ from the period mapping discussed here. Apparently, his description of the period mapping comes from Griffiths (as said on p. 210), but he gave no reference, so I'm not sure if that's how Griffiths did it.
It would be nice if someone could tell me how to make sense of this map $\Phi$ (either in Wells's way or somehow draw a connection from his words to the "standard" way), as the wording in Wells is clearly confusing.

The point of the period mapping is really to look not only at a single complex structure, but at "variations" or "families" of complex structures. The case of a single complex structure is only setup for the "real thing", which looks at multiple complex structures on the same manifold. Wells explicitly talks about this right after the definition you're asking about, so I'd suggest reading on in order to clarify things.
Indeed, if you only look at a single fixed complex structure on $X$, then the period mapping in this sense is a map from the singleton $\{X\}$ to $Gr_h(P^r(X, \mathbb{C}))$, i.e. a single point in $Gr_h(P^r(X, \mathbb{C}))$, which admittedly doesn't seem very interesting or very "mapping-like".
To see what's going on, let's forget about primitive cohomology for a moment and just work with the whole DeRham cohomology.
Suppose that $X$ is a smooth compact manifold and $\mathcal X$ is some set of complex structures on $X$, which all happen to make $X$ into a Kähler manifold with the same Hodge numbers. Fix $p$ and $q$. Then for any complex structure in $\mathcal X$, we get a subspace $H^{p,q}(X) \subset H^{r}(X,\Bbb C)$, i.e. a point $\mathbf{Gr}_h(H^{r}(X,\Bbb C))$. Different complex structures lead to different points in $\mathbf{Gr}_h(H^{r}(X,\Bbb C))$ and we obtain a genuine mapping
$$\mathcal X \to \mathbf{Gr}_h(H^{r}(X,\Bbb C))$$
This is a period mapping, restricting to primitive cohomology is just a variation of this idea.
If you continue reading in Wells, then you'll see how one might obtain such a family of complex structures and this relates the definition of the period mapping to other period mappings you might find.
Namely, if $X \xrightarrow{\pi} T$ is a proper holomorphic submersion, then the fibers are compact complex manifolds, which all happen to be diffeomorphic, so if they are Kähler, we get an induced period mapping. For details, you may consult Wells book, starting on page 211.
